# Changing QueryTimeout from sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, query-timeout

I'm experiencing problems with a slow running query that takes more than 30 seconds to execute at times, I would therefore like to increase my sqlsrv_query timeout.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

I'm having trouble with my PHP syntax, as the examples at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php did not really make sense to me.

Currently my connection / setup looks as follows:

```
$testServer = 'IP\servername,PORT';
$testDetails = array('Database' => 'DBNAME', 'UID' => 'USERNAME', 'PWD' => 'Password');
$testConnect = sqlsrv_connect($testServer, $testDetails);
```

My understanding is that I need to pass the timout details through as parameters within `sqlsrv_connect` but I'm not getting my syntax right.

(I have optimized the query as much as I can, unfortunately given the design of the db table I am not able to get it to return consistently in less than 30 seconds.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is actually a PHP error, and has nothing to do with the sqlsrv drivers; by default, the sqlsrv drivers will run a query until it receives a result.

> Key: QueryTimeout
>   Value: A positive integer value
>   Description: Sets the query timeout in seconds. **By default, the driver will wait indefinitely for results.**
>   <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

<sup>Source: [Options parameter - sqlsrv_query (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php#refsect1-function.sqlsrv-query-parameters)</sup>

---

The error is the [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) defined in the php.ini file - default 30 seconds. As the script runs over 30 seconds the parser terminates the script, throwing the fatal error.

To solve this error you can either change the `max_execution_time` setting in the php.ini file, or alternatively at the top of your script add:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", value); //The value will only be changed for this script!
```

Where `value` is the maximum time *in seconds* you want the script to run for.

---

As your question is asking about setting a timeout for queries, the syntax for that would be:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, array("QueryTimeout" => 30));
```

Where, again, `30` is the maximum time in seconds you want the query to run for.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer! (even including the sqlsrv_query syntax bit) I modified my php.ini and my problem has been resolved.

Comment: The "array("QueryTimeout" => 30)" solved a similar problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: Adding set_time_limit(300); to the php code that ran an expensive database query was a workaround that "fixed" another similar timeout issue I had in a php script on a slow, old and grumpy server.